# sql what is the order of variable evaluation

Tags: mysql, sql

```
SET @rowse := -1;
  SELECT
      @rowse := @rowse + 1 AS rowses ,
      STATION.LAT_N AS LAT_N
   FROM
      STATION
   ORDER BY STATION.LAT_N
```

What is the order of evaluation of the variable and order by.

1.Will the order by performed first and then the evaluation of @rowse := @rowse + 1 take place? Thus leading to sorted LAT_N and all the rowses are consecutive.

2. or the  @rowse := @rowse + 1  is first evaluated and assigned to every row and then order by on station.lat_n will take place leading to sorted LAT_N but possibility of non consecutive rowses.

In MySQL 1st takes place but I am not able to understand when ORDER BY is evaluated after SELECT according to MANUAL then how come case 1 takes place.
Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The documentation is not *that* precise about the question you ask. I find that it is usually safer to order the rows in a subquery first, then use the variable;

```
set @rowse := -1; 
select @rowse := @rowse + 1 as rowses , lat_n 
from (select * from station order by lat_n) s
```

Note that you don't need a separate statement to initialize the variable:

```
select @rowse := @rowse + 1 as rowses , lat_n  
from (select * from station order by lat_n) s
cross join (select @rowse := 0) r
```

User variables are tricky to use. They are now officially planned for deprecation in a future version od MySQL. If you are lucky enough to be running MySQL 8.0, this is simpler, safer and canonically done with window functions:

```
select row_number() over(order by lat_n) - 1 as rowses , lat_n as lat_n 
from station
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `row_number()`:

```
SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY STATION.LAT_N) - 1 as rowses,
       STATION.LAT_N AS LAT_N
FROM STATION
ORDER BY STATION.LAT_N;
```

The assignment of variables in MySQL `SELECT` statements has been deprecated since the release of 8.0.

Older versions of MySQL are inconsistent on whether the variable assignment respects ordering.  So, it is safest to use a subquery -- which materializes the order:

SELECT @rowse := @rowse + 1 AS rowses ,
S.LAT_N AS LAT_N
FROM (SELECT S.*
FROM STATION S
ORDER BY S.LAT_N
) s;

By the way, the same is true for `GROUP BY` as well.